# Jenkins configure system UI broken, clicking save and apply not working

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

We are using CloudBees Jenkins Distribution 2.277.4.3.
We are unable to save or apply the jenkins configure system changes.

Steps to reproduce:

Go to https://<jenkins_ui>/configure with any browser
Make a configuration change of any sort
Click on "Apply" or "Save".
nothing happens and the changes are not accepted.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from <2.277 ? Read Jenkins [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/).

Comment: CloudBees Jenkins Distribution upgrade from version 2.277.3.1 to 2.277.4.3.
upgraded from apt upgrade command

Comment: Can't speak to a minor increment on CJD (I just use the OSS); best to check their support. But I can refer you to : [Configuration Form Modernization](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.277/#configuration-form-modernization), which is the culprit [breaking many plugins](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=20741), when moving from < 2.263.4 to 2.277.1+